# rich:suggestionbox property not found

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I´m having some problems using a suggestionbox, i´ll paste some code to show my problem:
(Richfaces: 3.3.3)
**xhtml**

```html
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{CreateUser.cityName}" size="40"/>                  
<rich:suggestionbox width="290" suggestionAction="#{CreateUser.suggest}" var="city" for="input">
    <h:column>
       <h:outputText value="#{city.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <h:outputText value="#{city.state.name}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <h:graphicImage value="#{city.state.country.flagImage}" />
    </h:column>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

**Bean**
This is my suggest method.

```
public ArrayList<CityType> suggest(Object input) {
   String userInput = (String) input;
   ArrayList<CityType> ret = new ArrayList<CityType>();

   for (CityType state : cityTypes) {
      if ((state.getName().toLowerCase()).startsWith(userInput.toLowerCase())) {
         ret.add(state);
      }
    }
   return ret;
}
```

I´m getting this:

```
/account/createUser.xhtml: Property 'suggest' not found on type com.project.web.CreateUser_$$_javassist_seam_9
```

Thxs for your time!!!

Comment: seems to be configuration issue...do you have seam implemented...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [RichFaces 3 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_suggestionbox.html), your function should return a `List`, not an `ArrayList`, change your code to this:

```
public List<CityType> suggest(Object input) {
    String userInput = (String) input;
    List<CityType> ret = new ArrayList<CityType>();

    for (CityType state : cityTypes) {
        if ((state.getName().toLowerCase()).startsWith(userInput.toLowerCase())) {
            ret.add(state);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```